# How to create custom VBO action?

Tags: 7, actions, views

I need to update term references on nodes without updating the "changed" timestamp on the node.
If I use [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) with "modify entity values" as action I can update the term reference but it will also update the "changed" timestamp.

How can I code a custom VBO action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, an explanation of why the `changed` timestamp gets updated. Actions can declare the attribute

```
'behavior' => array('changes_property')
```

in their `hook_action_info` entry. This attribute causes VBO to automatically call Entity API's [entity_save](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_save/7) function after the action has been called. This function ends up calling [node_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7), which updates the `changed` timestamp.

To avoid this behavior, simply create your own custom action by implementing [hook_action_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_action_info/7) in a custom module and follow the `action_example` of the [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples). Make sure that your `hook_action_info` **omits** the attribute

```
'behavior' => array('changes_property')
```

Your action function will need to save the node or any other data by manipulating the database directly, or by making sure that you're using a function that doesn't trigger a `node_save` call.

Comment: _First, an explanation of why the changed timestamp gets updated_ ...then I was expecting the explanation on _How to create custom VBO action_

Comment: Thank you! I had defined the 'behavior' parameter and it was making my function not work properly. I removed it and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [infojunkie](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/767/infojunkie) is correct, however if you completely remove the attribute rather than just setting it to:

> 'behavior' => array()

then it will default back to:

> 'behavior' => array('changes_property')

and then you are back to the original problem.  This was a gotcha for me for a while today so hoping to save someone some trouble in the future.

(See plugins/operation_types/action.class.php lines 22-25 in the https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations module on drupal.org for details.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that using:

```
'behavior' => array()
```

still reverts to the default as the VBO code adds the default if empty($this->operationInfo['behavior']))...

To avoid this set behaviour to something else (made up will do) such as.

```
'behavior' => array('ignore')
```