# VBO calls entity_save after custom action is triggered. How to stop that?

Tags: views, actions

I have VBO custom actions defined and it gets triggered. Also, I do NOT have 'behavior' => array('changes_property') defined in my hook_actions_info() as described in [How to create custom VBO action?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30910/how-to-create-custom-vbo-action)

I see that my custom action is getting triggered and does custom operations and finally saves by creating new node revision. Weird part is that entity_save operation is being called after this and it is updating node table with older version of node rather than new vesrion created by custom funtion.

How can I stop or prevent vbo to call entity_save and just perform custom action?

Any insights will be greatly helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old issue, but I literally just had the same problem and after banging my head off of it all day I found upon a solution through the d.o issue queue.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2254871

I applied the patch from #42 and it solved it right away after setting `'behavior' => array()`.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: And you posting this sure saved me time and helped alot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same type of issue where I had removed

> 'behavior' => array('changes_property')

from my custom action's definition. However on digging in, I found in plugins/operation_types/action.class.php lines 22-25 that if you don't specify the 'behavior' attribute in your definition it gets set to

> array('changes_property')

by default. To prevent entity_save from running, set it to an empty array as in:

> 'behavior' => array()

then it should start working as you expect.